# How to print Hello World in terminal using the command tex

Tags: terminal-output

While I went through the tutorial on Latex I couldn't get how to print "Hello World" using command `tex` as illustrated in [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Installation).The command I would like to execute in terminal is:

`tex '\empty Hello world!\bye'`.

But the error I'm getting is:

`! I can't find file Hello`

`<*> \empty Hello`

Could anyone tell me is there anything else needed to print this(Hello World) statement in the terminal using the command `tex`.

Comment: There is some misunderstanding: `tex '\empty Hello World!\bye'` does not print the Hello World string on the terminal itself, but uses the standard output file `texput.dvi` then. Are you using the correct `'` characters? (If pdftex is used, the file is called texput.pdf then)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer:that's right.But I can't get the standard output file `textput.dvi`.I first tried using the `'` character then tried using the `backslash`character but still can't get the output file.Could you help me.

Comment: I entered the command on a terminal and there was no error, I just copied the command from the screen and inserted it on the command line, there was no error. I imagine some strange encoding on your terminal or another typo

Comment: @ChristianHupfer:Thanks.I'm using Windows 7.I'm typing from command prompt and I'm using TEX live package.So does these specifications means a change in the command statement said in wikibooks?.It's also an system used from a library(restricted access by admin).

Comment: Windows 7... some important information ... I think you should use `"` instead of `'`, but I don't use Windows at all, so it's just a guess

Comment: @ChristianHupfer:yeah that really worked.Thanks.

Comment: run only `tex` and you are in TeXs interactive mode. Insert now `hello World <enter>` and then `\bye`.

Comment: @Herbert:When I entered `hello World <enter>` after entering `tex`  in command prompt in Windows 7 it says  `!I can't find file 'hello'`.Even before entering `\bye` it produces the mentioned error and it ask to type another input file.

Comment: You have to start `TeX` with `tex <enter>`  and then input `Hello World`

Comment: @Herbert:I got the result and the problem was that `\relax` wasn't specified for the `tex` command anyway I think that's a better method than the one specified in wikibooks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command

```
tex '\empty {Hello World!}\bye'
```

only works on a Unix-like terminal, for Windows command prompt, the `'` characters has to be replaced by `"` double quotes, it is

```
tex "\empty {Hello World!}\bye"
```

In either case, a file called `texput.dvi` is generated, if `pdftex` is used, the file will be called `texput.pdf` then.

This is basically a test whether the tex installation was successful.